# Codename One Crash Protection Log Emails

Tags: codenameone

We've activated the Log.bindCrashProtection(true) feature on a number of our apps over the last two months.

In the first week or so we received a number of crash logs that we attended to as they came in but we have not received any new emails since 2020-11-02.

I did a Test yesterday (2020-12-02) where I forced a Null Pointer on the EDT on one of our app but we did not receive any new messages from Codename One.

Is this feature still available and if yes is there any limit on the number of Emails perhaps that we have hit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You need to contact our support in the website chat.

There are a few problems that might occur e.g. if an email bounces once then our email provider can block you and we would need to unblock you manually.

Comment: Thanks Shai, we will make contact with the support desk.